# animation between two UITextviews

Tags: iphone, ios6

```
[baseview addSubview:textView1];
textView1.alpha = 0.0;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:textView1 cache:YES];
textView1.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];

[baseview addSubview:textView2];
textView2.alpha = 0.0;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:textView2 cache:YES];
textView2.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

How i can animate between these two textviews.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work to hide the first text view and show the second one:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:textView1 cache:YES];
{
    textView1.alpha = 0.0;
    textView2.alpha = 1.0;
}
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Maybe you have to set the parent view as animation view (e.g. `self.view`).